# AS3 Air remote external swf can not access local apk

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

*I'm developing an android file by using flash cs5 air extention.
I know the basic crossdomain policy and server to server connections. And I searched many pages but there is no solution about this.*

My "container.apk" loads "external.swf" from the server.. And I want to be able to reach the variables and functions in "container.apk" from "external.swf".
 But I can't reach any function on my container (application file .apk) from my external module swf (remote file).. I mean, I'm trying to reach container.apk's functions from the loaded swf. **Like when a button clicked on "external.swf" it should effect a function in "container.apk".**

Also here are some error codes that I'm getting ;

**SecurityError: Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: parent: http://******.com/external.swf cannot access app:/container.swf**

And the loading function of my container ;

```
var l:Loader = new Loader;
var externalSWF:MovieClip;
var contextC:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 
contextC.checkPolicyFile = false;
contextC.allowCodeImport = true;
l.load(new URLRequest(filePath), contextC);
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);


function loadComplete(evt:Event){
    l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
    externalSWF = l.content as MovieClip;
    MovieClip(root).addChild(externalSWF);
}
```

Comment: This may not be possible from a mobile app. Normally external swf access to AIR applications is via a [sandbox bridge](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security_5.html), however this requires an iframe embedded using html. This may be possible using [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html), though I'm unsure of the implimentation.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, Just like you said. Neither sandbox bridge nor the saving files locally works on mobile. Actually I changed all the architecture for passing security violations. But somehow I should use the StageWebView and it doesnt let me to use it from external.swf. Is there any way to bridge to container to use StageWebView?

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond. Unfortunately, looking in to StageWebView to solve a similar problem, I have found that there is no way to bridge content through that method either and Adobe's documentation reflects this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by design, loaded SWFs are sandboxed.

Imagine the scenario where you have a Flash website and want to load Flash games for example. If loaded children had access to parent, a malicious SWF could get server access through your loader SWF for example.

It also doesn't help that what you're trying to do is even more dangerous, by having access to the APK and its permissions, a loaded SWF could in theory take over the phone.

It should however work the other way round, the loader host should be able to access anything inside the loaded SWF, so I'm afraid you'll have to architect your app with this in mind.

Comment: But I'm the developer. I mean there should be a way to specify the both file (container and swf) to access each other. Just like how "allowDomain" allow acces from a specific website, there should be method to allow external files to access the container

Comment: Well, you might be the developer, but if your webserver is compromised and your external.swf replaced you'd potentially screw all your Android app users. I don't know, there might be a way around this limitation, but you see the problem :)

Comment: Then it would be the same for crossdomain policy. Someone can take the external.swf's server down and replace it with externalInterface support and take every Android phones down. I think there should be a way to let the external swf to reach the container app. Cause I heard some Air developers using this for updating their product modules. But their methods doesnt work on Android based applications

Comment: Hmm, if you can access the contents of the APK, maybe you can replace an SWF there and load it locally?

Comment: Thanks for trying to be helpful dain. I tried to load it locally and reload the locally saved file. And it still doesnt allow me to reach the container.

Comment: Oh well, I wish I could help more. Wild guess, but maybe you could use this? http://www.jamesward.com/2011/04/26/introducing-mixing-loom-runtime-actionscript-bytecode-modification/